# Is it possible to enable array bounds checking in g++?

Tags: g++, c++

Is it possible to have g++ show an error when compiling the following file with some flag?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int arr[ 2 ];

   cout << arr[ 4 ] << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I saw some things like `gcc -Wall -O2 main.c` which only works with C, not C++.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic` don't generate warnings for this program :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a static analyser such as [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/). When run on your above code:

```
$ cppcheck --enable=all test.cpp
Checking test.cpp...
[test.cpp:6]: (style) Variable 'arr' is not assigned a value
[test.cpp:8]: (error) Array 'arr[2]' index 4 out of bounds
```

You can integrate Cppcheck into your build procedure and consider your code built successfully only if Cppcheck passes.

Answer (score 8):

Not at compile time. You might be able to check that at runtime though.

For that take a look at:
[Runtime array bounds checking with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291114/runtime-array-bounds-checking-with-g)

Answer (score 3):

For raw arrays, I don't think so, because `-fbounds-check` didn't work with your example and MingW g++ 4.4.1, and because the old 3.x docs I have say

> -fbounds-check
>
> For front-ends that support it,
>   generate additional code to check that
>   indices used to access arrays are
>   within the declared range. This is
>   currently only supported by the Java
>   and Fortran 77 front-ends, where this
>   option defaults to true and false
>   respectively.

However, with `std::vector` you can use `at` to have a slightly impractical run-time bounds-checking (generates exception). And you can use a special debug version of the standard library, that provides practical run-time bounds-checking for `[]`. For example, when compiling…

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<int>  arr( 2 );

   cout << arr[ 4 ] << endl;
}
```

… you get different respectively non-checking and checking behavior for the release and debug versions of the g++ standard library implementation:

```
C:\test> g++ x.cpp & a
4083049

C:\test> g++ x.cpp -D _GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC & a
c:\program files\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/include/c++/debug/vector:265:
    error: attempt to subscript container with out-of-bounds index 4, but
    container only holds 2 elements.

Objects involved in the operation:
sequence "this" @ 0x0x22ff1c {
  type = NSt7__debug6vectorIiSaIiEEE;
}

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

C:\test> _
```

Reportedly for newer g++ versions (after 4.0) you don't need the `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` symbol. For details, see the [GNU documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt03ch17s02.html).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: `{boost,std::tr1,std}::array` has `at` as well.

Comment: The -fbounds-check seems to only work if optimizations are turned on.  So I expected `-O -fbounds-check` to work - but it doesn't in the OP's example just like you said.  However `-fsanitize=address,undefined` does catch it: https://godbolt.org/z/5MPx3d668

Answer (score 2):

I recall seeing a gcc or g++ warning message from ffmpeg or x264 along the lines of

"warning index of array may be out of bounds"

http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2000-07/msg01000.html

seems like it probably made it in.

The constraint is that you have an example like yours above. as soon as you have have variables instead of literals it is not possible. except perhaps in a simple loop.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer), ffmpeg uses AddressSanitizer. This might be its output. More on AddressSanitizer [in an A to another Q](//stackoverflow.com/a/17637383/2157640).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace arrays with `std::vector`. Vector has accessor member function ([`std::vector::at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/)) that does bounds checking at runtime.

Compile time check for buffer overflow is a very hard undecidable problem, unfortunately. It's usually handled by a full blown static analysis tool.