# Any debug flag in g++ to check array index

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I build the program below with g++ (g++ - g3 main.cpp) and VisualStudio 2013 (VS) 
in debug mode.When run - VS exits with assert complaining about index range issue 
but g++ version under Ubuntu 13.10 runs fine and it prints vi[11] = 11.

I understand - C++ Standard does not specify behavior for my case but 
warning or crash in my case would be nice.

Is there any flag in gcc(or clang) to enable array index out of range check 
during build ? 
If no is any good analysis tool for that ?

```
int main() { 
    vector<int> vi(8); 
    vi.push_back(1); 
    vi.push_back(2); 

    vi[11] = 11; 
    std::cout << "Vi[11]=" << vi[11] << std::endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778552/is-it-possible-to-enable-array-bounds-checking-in-g

Comment: This looks quite helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291114/runtime-array-bounds-checking-with-g

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes, it does.

Comment: Apart from the tools recommended on the above links, you might consider accessing your array elements with as `vi.at(11)`. In this case, an exception is thrown on the line violating the bound. It does have a performance penalty though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC STL bound checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594686/gcc-stl-bound-checking)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice tool for bounds check: http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/
Regarding gcc `-Warray-bounds` flag may help.